# Securing filebeat connection to logstash through API Key

Tags: security, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

Is it possible to secure the communication **between filebeat and logstash** with a token of some kind?

I know that it is possible to secure the filebeat --> logstash connection through HTTPS mutual authentication, but I feel they are pretty hard to manage if we have many different filebeat clients (prove me wrong and I'll happily change my mind).

I am also aware that it is possible to secure the logstash --> elastic connection with API keys, but that's not what I need, I need securing from filebeat to logstash.

## Use case

I'm setting up a centralized ELK stack for log analytics that will be used to collect logs from a variety of different systems, some may be actual servers, most will be developer's workstations.

I would like to setup a system in which a developer logs into a secured internal service, asks for a token, and start streaming logs from her/his workstation right away.

If a breach is detected I would like it to be a simple process: it should be enough to invalidate the previous token that has been leaked and issue a new one, and then removing from ES the unwanted log entries streamed by the leaked token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible, the only way to secure the communication between **filebeat** and **logstash** is using [SSL certificates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuring-ssl-logstash.html#configuring-ssl-logstash).

The closest you can get of what you want is if you send the **filebeat** logs directly to **elasticsearch**, then you would be able to use an [API key](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/securing-communication-elasticsearch.html), this needs security enabled in elasticsearch.

In both cases you would need to configure the `filebeat.yml` file for the developer's workstation.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that